# How to run multiple R scripts from one script in a Docker Container

Tags: r, docker

I've got a script called initiate.R which runs two other scripts, like so:

```
source("Step1_databaseConnection.R")
source("Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R")
```

In my dockerfile I have defined the following:

```
COPY Step1_databaseConnection.R  /home/project/Step1_databaseConnection.R

COPY Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R  /home/project/Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R

COPY initiate.R  /home/project/initiate.R

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/Rscript", "/home/project/initiate.R"]
```

However, I get the following error when running the task on AWS: cannot open file 'Step1_databaseConnection.R': No such file or directory

When I change my dockerfile to run the two scripts separately it works. Here is the code that works:

```
COPY Step1_databaseConnection.R  /home/project/Step1_databaseConnection.R

COPY Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R  /home/project/Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R

COPY initiate.R  /home/project/initiate.R

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/Rscript", "/home/project/Step1_databaseConnection.R"]

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/Rscript", "/home/project/Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R"]
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure the import paths of `Step1_databaseConnection.R ` and `Step2_buildingDateInfoAndMainFlowInfo.R ` scripts in your `initiate.R` script correctly point to those files inside the docker container?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try. They are all copied to the same directory so didn't think that would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second try with executing the scripts by hand, you are using absolute paths. However, the first try starts the script with the current working directory of docker es working directory of R. This is not the file location. Therefore you have first move to this location with `WORKDIR filepath`. afterthet you can execute the script as expected.